# Openlayers: How to keep a layer zIndex as set

Tags: z-index, openlayers

**I am using OpenLayers 2.13.1.**

I have a vector layer and some WMS layers in a map. WMS layers can be added and removed but the vector layer always remains in map.

The vector layer is interactive therefore I want to keep that always on top of the WMS layer. I keep the zIndex of the vector over `1000` and keep zIndex of all WMS layers bellow `1000`.
The problem occurs when I remove a WMS layer from the map: the vector layer goes bellow. I have noticed that method `map.resetLayersZIndex()` is invoked when I remove a layer which sets the zIndex according to the order in the layers array of the map.

**Is there a way to keep the zIndex same as I set?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your important layer to the end of the map's layers-array after each addition of a layer:

```
    map = ...
    vectorLayer = ...

    map.events.register('addlayer', map, function() {

            this.setLayerIndex(vectorLayer, this.layers.length);
    });
```